# Can first descendent be selected directly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, traversal

I am currently using `find()` and `first()` method to select the first descendent element from each of the `<div>` elements that contains the `parent` class. But I find this quite cumbersome since `find()` method would produce a set of matched elements before the first element is being picked. The following is the skeleton of my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class=parent>
 <ul>
  <li>random characters</li>
  <li>random characters</li>
  <li>random characters</li>
  <li>random characters</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class=parent>
 <ul>
  <li>random characters</li>
  <li>random characters</li>
  <li>random characters</li>
  <li>random characters</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class=non-parent>
 <ul>
  <li>random characters</li>
  <li>random characters</li>
  <li>random characters</li>
  <li>random characters</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class=parent>
 <ul>
  <li>random characters</li>
  <li>random characters</li>
  <li>random characters</li>
  <li>random characters</li>
 </ul>
</div>
// .....the list continues
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.parent').each(function() {
 $(this).find('ul li').first().css('color', 'red');
// do other stuff (on other elements) within each loop
});
```

I have seen people using `$(".parent li:first")` selector. But, because I am doing it in a loop, I am not sure how or whether if this could be done and would like some advice. Thanks.

**Clarification**:

I need to do other stuff on other elements not shown in the HTML within `each` loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on both the outer loop and the `:first` selector, then use this:

```
$('.parent').each(function() {
    $(this).find('li:first').css('color', 'red');
    // do other stuff within each loop
});
```

Note that the following will *not* work:

```
$('.parent li:first').css('color', 'red');
```

....because it will simply select the first `li` descendant across all `.parent` elements.

Comment: `:first` and `:first-child` are not the same thing. `:first-child` selects all elements that are the first child of their parent, while `:first` filters the results to only the first match.

Comment: @nbrooks - Is there something about my post that led you to believe I didn't understand that? If so, I'll make it more clear. Specifically, notice the second half of my answer which implies the difference.

Comment: Well you made a point of saying that the code specified wouldn't work, but nobody suggested that so I thought you had misread. The same line of code works if you use `:first-child`. Just clarifying. Good answer anyway :)

Comment: The code `$(".parent li:first")` appears in the OP's question. Your comments are probably useful to future visitors, though, so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to loop over the first element in each parent, you can do this:

```
$('.parent ul li:first-child').each(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
    // do other stuff within each loop
});
```

That doesn't have to be done in a loop though, as the `.css()` method will operate on all matched elements. This works too:

```
$('.parent ul li:first-child').css('color', 'red');
```

That will change all of them.

Another option if you want to loop over all `li`s is:

```
$('.parent ul li').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(":first-child"))
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    // do other stuff within each loop
});
```

UPDATE:
If you want to loop over each parent than do the other check subsequently, the following would be useful:

```
$('.parent').each(function() {
    // I assume that even if other uls are in parent, the ul you target is first

    $(this).find("ul li:first-child").first().css('color', 'red');

    // do other stuff within each loop
});
```

Comment: I assumed that what you want to do in the loop involved the same element, but you get the idea.

Comment: I mean other elements not shown in my html. Sorry. I updated the clarification in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

And by the way, you dont need the foreach...! Apply your css modifications directly to the collection!

```
$('.parent ul li:first-child').css('color', 'red');
```

Please, refer to this working example http://jsfiddle.net/9ej5H/

Note that Zee Tee answer is ok too, but less readable.

Comment: Yes, I understand first-child, but `<li>` is not a child but a grandchild.

Comment: I need the `each` loop to do something else. lwburk got the answer.

Comment: got your point, you need the other .parent divs - then his answer is better! (:

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the [index selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq/): `$(".parent ul li:eq(0)")`

or

`$(".parent ul li").eq(0)`

Just a note: `0` is the first one.